# azure table services authentication

Tags: azure, azure-storage

while writing application using nodejs/azure and table services, how can we set what type of authorization should be used.
Shared Key Lite (or) Shared Key.

How can we set that?

Comment: You probably can't. Why do you want to?

Comment: I've not tried node.js personally but I believe if you use node.js SDK for Windows Azure, it will take care of this for you. You can download it from here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you're accessing Table Services. If you use the SDK you can do it like this:

**Shared Key**

```
var sharedKey = = new SharedKeyTable(storageAccount, storageAccessKey, usePathStyleUri);
var tableService = azure.createTableService(null, null, null, sharedKey);
```

**Shared Key Lite**

```
var sharedKeyLite = = new SharedKeyLiteTable(storageAccount, storageAccessKey, usePathStyleUri);
var tableService = azure.createTableService(null, null, null, sharedKeyLite);
```

[Take a look at the code](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tableservice.js) and you'll see that Shared Key will be used if you omit the authentication provider.

If you use `http.request` you need to specify the type in the authorization header:

```
Authorization="[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] <AccountName>:<Signature>"
```

So your code will be something like this:

```
var http = require('http');

function doSomethingWithTables() {
    var settings = {
        host: ...,
        port: 80,
        path: ...,
        headers: {},
        method: 'GET'
    };
    settings.headers['Authorization'] = 'SharedKeyLite myaccount:xxiofojpfzaopfiaz';

    var req = http.request(settings);
    req.write(...);
    req.on('response', function(res){
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not using SDK. I am using node.js and Azure...how to do I do that ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. But you should take a look at the SDK for Node.js before building something yourself.